# Converting a radical to a mixed radical

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Say I have $\sqrt{\frac{2}{9}}$. How would I convert this to a mixed radical where the radicand is a **whole number**?

I can convert the $\sqrt{8}$ to a mixed radical easily, $2\sqrt{2}$, but this fraction is tripping me up.

Comment: Do you have ((the square root of 2) over 8), or (the square root of (2 over 8))?  Can you be more specific about the form you want to convert to?

Comment: I have the square root of (2 over 8), where 2 over 8 is a fraction. I want to convert it into a mixed radical where the radicand is a whole number.

Comment: @number 11: If you accept a rational number factor, you have infinitely many. For instance $\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{8}}=\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{1}=\dfrac{1}{4}\sqrt{2}=\ldots $

Comment: @Américo Tavares- I made a correction (2/9 as opposed to 2/8). My mistake, sorry.

Comment: @number 11: The situation is similar: $\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{9}}=\dfrac{1}{3}\sqrt{2}=\dfrac{1}{6}\sqrt{8}=\ldots $

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{2}{9}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{9}} = \frac{1}{3}\sqrt{2}$, no?

Comment: The answer 1/3 square root 2 is exactly the answer I want. How did you get 1/3 though? I'm assuming it has something to do with the square root of 9

Comment: _"I'm assuming it has something to do with the square root of 9."_  Yes.  Hint: What's $3 \times 3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt{\frac{2}{9}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{9}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: What I wanted is 1/3 sqrt 2, a mixed radical with a whole radicand.

Comment: @DMan: Your respones are quite confusing... You're aware that $(1/3)\sqrt{2}$ is the same thing as $\sqrt{2}/3$, right?

Comment: @Hans- Oops, you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by the radicand is a "whole number"? In your example $\sqrt{8}=2\sqrt{2}$ in both sides of the equation the radicand is a whole number.

In any case, it doesn't really matter because the problem as you stated it doesn't have a radical at all when you simplify: $\sqrt{\frac{2}{8}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{4}}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I assumed the first 2 is called the index, and the second was the radicand. Also, sorry for the mistake, I wanted 2/9 as opposed to 2/8.